# Vim iskeyword doesn't work

Tags: vim

my iskeyword is iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,(,),=,[,],<,>,: 
 but when i'm using ctrl+arrows vim jumps only to spaces, but not others symbols.

Comment: when words separated by : character (some:words:for:example) i want to move cursor word by word after : symbol using w or b (ctrl+arrows), but now i can just move cursor to beginning of text or to the end if they aren't separated by spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `ctrl+arrows` behave like W and B while `ctrl+shift+arrows` as w and b. Try to use the later or even better try to use the simpler and *vimier* w and b.

Comment: i've used also w and b, but same effect

Comment: my mistake. on insert mode ctrl+arrows are w and b, but in normal mode they are W and B.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you want brackets or parentheses excluded from word selection.

So what you want to do, is removing `(` `)` `{` `}` from `iskeyword`.

I have tried the following in my .vimrc and it seems to work (`w`or `*` does not include `(`):

`set iskeyword-={,},[,],(,)`

(The important character here is `-`which means these characters should be **removed** from`iskeyword`)

By default `iskeyword` only includes digit and letters so it should not be necessary to remove them explicitly but a plugin might be messing iskeyword definition.